how to stop Jenkins from using result-files from branches which do not exist anymore in github
(Jenkins-noob, so it can be that what I'm looking for is obvious, but I just don't know it. I have searched both Google and here to find a similar question, but could not find it (but probably I searched wrong))
We have a daily-check Jenkins job which parses the results of multiple pipelines and tell us if they all passed or failed and with that we say if our daily CICD is OK / failed.
It uses the following command (not written by me, the job was already existing when I joined the team, but it now fails on an old branch):
STATUS_BASE_NAME=/tmp/${NODE_NAME}__status

# Write an empty file to prevent cat having an error if no status_* files could be found
echo "SUCCESS" > ${STATUS_BASE_NAME}_always_there

echo "Overview of stored job statuses:"
for file in ${STATUS_BASE_NAME}_*; do status=`cat "${file}"`; echo "${file}: ${status}"; done

# Check if there are any FAILED results (invert the result of grep to make this job fail if there are)
! cat ${STATUS_BASE_NAME}_* | grep FAILURE

But STATUS_BASE_NAME also finds results for old branches which already have been deleted in bitbucket.
Now I have the following question: 
How can we manually make sure that those old result files are deleted? Or even better: how can we do this automatically?

Information provided in question is not enough, there is no reference of any bitbucket branch in the script you provided.

What if you were to delete the file at the end of the daily check job? That would mean every time this runs it would only have the jobs since yesterday.

@RahulSharma: First thank you for your reply.
This particular job itself does not use the bitbucket branches directly. It only uses files which were created for a the run of a particular branch using /tmp/${NODE_NAME}__status. I assumed that was set by Jenkins itself, since I did not find it anywhere in a Jenkinsfile. (As already said I'm a Jenkins noob and the people who wrote this have left our team).

@MB: Also you thank you for your reply.
I will have to check if every pipeline it looks upon is really ran every day. If it is it sounds like a valid solution. If not I will come back (I am not at work at the moment so can't check at this moment)

@MB: I can't mark your answer as the solution, but deleting the old branches at the end did the trick.

@Nemelis great to hear
